# How to solve transfer function of a bandpass filter with Butterworth approximation?

Tags: amplifier, filter

How can I calculate the transfer function of this bandpass filter characteristic with Butterworth approximation?

[image]

- **\$A_{max}\$** = 0,9 dB
- **\$A_{min}\$** = 6,5 dB
- **\$\omega\$3** = 100
- **\$\omega\$1** = 300
- **\$\omega\$2** = 1100
- **\$\omega\$4** = 3300

Which steps do I have to take and what are some good resources for learning these kinds of filter design problems?

Answer (score 1):

Volki, be aware that the design will be rather involved.
Here is a short summary of the main steps (active filter design):

1. Based on the given values (center frequency, bandwidth, midband gain, attenuation values) you must use existing formulas for the bandpass-lowpass transformation. As a result, you have corresponding lowpass requirements and you can calculate the corresponding lowpass order (n=2,3,..).
2. Applying again corresponding equations you can transform the lowpss poles back to the bandpass poles.
3. Now you have two alternatives for pole allocation (depending on the required filter order):

   - Series connection of active lowpass and highpass sections
   - Active bandpass stage (or series connection of several stages).

---

For passive topologies, you must rely on filter catalogues. In any case - I strongly recommend to make use from filter design programs which are available. For example:

Passive: AADE;
Active: Filter Free, FilterLab, FilterPro

Comment: A first look on the given data has shown that a second-order bandpass can meet the requirements.